# Regular Expression Engine Testing

Tags: c++, regex

I wrote my own Regular Expression Engine.
Does anybody know how to test it, I can go ahead the test with couple of Regular Expression and some input data.
but I need some huge list of regular expressions to test with.

Comment: Why would anyone write their own regex engine these days?

Comment: +1 I'd be interested in such  a resource, too.

Comment: @John Speed, smallness, lack of dependencies, fun.

Comment: I am taking course on Theory of Computation and I found RE is good to start for NFA,DFA and Thompson to try out.

Comment: @unapersson : I am referring book http://www.amazon.com/Compiler-Design-C-Prentice-Hall-software/dp/0131550454

Comment: I'd imagine writing a (huge) list of test cases would take just a fraction of the time it'd take to implement a regex engine...

Comment: @Bart I implemented one in C++, based on Kernighan & Plauger's code from Software Tools In Pascal in an afternoon. Of course, getting all the bugs out took a little longer :-) But it's really not that complicated.

Comment: @unapersson, okay, then I guess it truly is a "regular" expression parser, and not a PCRE-flavored one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) has some tests as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/index.html) and [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/xpressive/index.html) test suites are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code compatible with unit testing? Testing the components that make up the whole might have some value.